# What is the in-universe name of the drum style in Star Wars: Eclipse?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, star-wars-eclipse

What is the style of drumming called in Star Wars: Eclipse, [as seen in the official Eclipse trailer?](https://youtu.be/4cJpiOPKH14)

[image: Drumming 1]
[image: Drumming 2]

Looking for canon in-universe details; although any real life inspiration would also be interesting supplement to answer.

Comment: There is essentially no public information about this game yet. Asking for the name of a music style never before seen in Star Wars is a bit... hopeful.

Comment: Well, we do know at least wreckpunk was popular within this era by fringers, but I don’t think this is an example of that music genre.

Answer (score 14):

Japanese Taiko drumming.  I note there are Japanese style costumes in the trailer as well.

History of
https://www.taiko-center.co.jp/english/history_of_taiko.html

(Please forgive this edit / photo addition)

[image]

Comment: If you're certain there's no in-universe name you should [edit] that in.

Comment: I appreciate the supplemental details about the real-world inspiration.

Comment: upvoting soley for Teebo